# Generic container type (higher kind) for "map" in scala

Tags: scala, generics, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to define a case class that is parameterized with a container type (higher kind). This container type can be anything as long as it has a map method defined.

I would like to achieve this result suggested by the following code:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

case class Test[A, C[A]](init: A, trans: Map[A,C[A]]) {
  def convert[B](conv: A => B): Test[B, C[B]] = {
    val _init = conv(init)
    val _trans = trans map {case (k,v) => (conv(k) -> (v map {x => conv(x)})}
    Test(_init, _trans)
  }
}
```

the problem lies in the `v map {x => conv(x)}` part of the code. Since no bound was defined for `C[A]` it, obviously, does not compile.

The thing is that this container type can be an `Id` (Scalaz style, but with `map` instead of `|>`), and `Option`, or a collection (`Seq`, `Set`, `List`, etc.)

Is there any way to tell the scala compiler that the container type will must have the `map` method?

Comment: How about a functor typeclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is by using the [**Functor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) type class.
For example here is an example using [Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats).
*(You could do the same using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz))*.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor.toFunctorOps

final case class Test[A, C[_]](init: A, trans: Map[A,C[A]])(implicit CFunctor: Functor[C]) {
  def convert[B](conv: A => B): Test[B, C] = {
    val _init = conv(init)
    val _trans = trans map { case (k,v) => conv(k) -> v.map(x => conv(x)) }
    Test(_init, _trans)
  }
}
```

However, if for some reason you can't or don't want to use Cats/Scalaz, you could try [**Structural Types**](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types).

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

final case class Test[A, C[A] <: { def map[B](f: A => B): C[B]}](init: A, trans: Map[A,C[A]]){
  def convert[B](conv: A => B): Test[B, C] = {
    val _init = conv(init)
    val _trans = trans map { case (k,v) => conv(k) -> v.map(x => conv(x)) }
    Test(_init, _trans)
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, note that the last one will work for `Option`, but will fail for `List`, simple because the `map` method in List receives an implicit `CanBuildFrom`, and for that reason it isn't equals to the one you want.

Comment: Thank you, Luis Miguel. But, if you could help me a little more. I don't have experience with Cats. When I tried to apply your example and instantiate the Test class I got the following error message: `could not find implicit value for parameter CFunctor: cats.Functor[Set]`. I am guessing I have to provide the implicit parameter, but how would I do that?

Comment: Hi @Jeff , the easy way is to just import `cats.implicits._`, that brings almost  all the library in scope. Or if you only want the **Functor** of set you can get it from `cats.instances.set._` that brings all implicit instances for `Set` - Including **Functor[Set]**. For a more detailed explanation read the [Cats import guide](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html).